# Retrieve Heap memory size and its usage statistics etc...?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, heap-memory

Lets say I open some application or process. Did some work with that. Now I closed it.

Need to know whether this application caused any memory leak.
i.e used up some heap memory and not cleared it properly.

Can I get this statistics some how? I'm using Visual Studio (for development) under Windows OS.

Even I would be interested in knowing this information for any 3rd party application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an application closes all resources are automatically released by Windows.

A quick & dirty tool to get an indication for memory/resource-leaks inside an application is Perfmon.

The actions executed by an application, can cause other processes to use more memory. SQL Server can make its cache size bigger, maybe you have opened Word or Explorer, the Windows Search engine might kick in because you saved some file. The virus scanner can be more active, etc.....

Comment: Then how is leads to memory leak. Even after we close any application, heap memory is still into existence right!?

Comment: When an application closes, its returns all its memory on the heap to the OS. This does not mean that the number of available bytes will be the same as before the app started. In an OS happens a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at CrtSetDbgFlag:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs(v=VS.100).aspx